# About "Calculate Pointer in C# and AutoIT"

Tags: c#, memory, autoit

I Wanna read memory by pointer array. But I don't know how to add the calculate offsets to the address.
Here is the class that I am using.
**Here's code in C# :**

```
public int ReadInt(int iMemoryAddress, int[] iOffsets)
    {
        int iFinalAddress = CalculatePointer(iMemoryAddress, iOffsets);
        byte[] bBuffer = new byte[4];
        IntPtr ptrBytesRead;
        MAPI.ReadProcessMemory(hReadProcess, (IntPtr)iFinalAddress, bBuffer, 4, out ptrBytesRead);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bBuffer, 0);
    }
private int CalculatePointer(int iMemoryAddress, int[] iOffsets)
    {
        int iPointerCount = iOffsets.Length - 1; IntPtr ptrBytesRead; byte[] bBuffer = new byte[4]; int iTemporaryAddress = 0;

        if (iPointerCount == 0)
            iTemporaryAddress = iMemoryAddress;

        for (int i = 0; i <= iPointerCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == iPointerCount)
            {
                MAPI.ReadProcessMemory(hReadProcess, (IntPtr)iTemporaryAddress, bBuffer, 4, out ptrBytesRead);
                iTemporaryAddress = Dec(CreateAddress(bBuffer)) + iOffsets[i];
                return iTemporaryAddress;
            }
            else if (i == 0)
            {
                MAPI.ReadProcessMemory(hReadProcess, (IntPtr)iMemoryAddress, bBuffer, 4, out ptrBytesRead);
                iTemporaryAddress = Dec(CreateAddress(bBuffer)) + iOffsets[0];
            }
            else
            {
                MAPI.ReadProcessMemory(hReadProcess, (IntPtr)iTemporaryAddress, bBuffer, 4, out ptrBytesRead);
                iTemporaryAddress = Dec(CreateAddress(bBuffer)) + iOffsets[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
public int Dec(string sHex)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(sHex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
```

**Here's code in AutoIT**

```
Func _MemoryPointerRead($IV_ADDRESS, $AH_HANDLE, $av_Offset, $SV_TYPE = 'dword')

If IsArray($av_Offset) Then
    If IsArray($AH_HANDLE) Then
        Local $iv_PointerCount = UBound($av_Offset) - 1
    Else
        SetError(2)
        Return 0
    EndIf
Else
    SetError(1)
    Return 0
EndIf

Local $iv_Data[2], $i
Local $V_BUFFER = DllStructCreate('dword')

For $i = 0 To $iv_PointerCount

    If $i = $iv_PointerCount Then
        $V_BUFFER = DllStructCreate($SV_TYPE)
        If @error Then
            SetError(@error + 2)
            Return 0
        EndIf

        $IV_ADDRESS = '0x' & Hex($iv_Data[1] + $av_Offset[$i])
        DllCall($AH_HANDLE[0], 'int', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'int', $AH_HANDLE[1], 'int', $IV_ADDRESS, 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($V_BUFFER), 'int', DllStructGetSize($V_BUFFER), 'int', '')
        If @error Then
            SetError(7)
            Return 0
        EndIf
        $iv_Data[1] = DllStructGetData($V_BUFFER, 1)

    ElseIf $i = 0 Then
        DllCall($AH_HANDLE[0], 'int', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'int', $AH_HANDLE[1], 'int', $IV_ADDRESS, 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($V_BUFFER), 'int', DllStructGetSize($V_BUFFER), 'int', '')
        If @error Then
            SetError(7)
            Return 0
        EndIf
        MsgBox(0,0,$iv_Data[1])
        $iv_Data[1] = DllStructGetData($V_BUFFER, 1)
    Else
        $IV_ADDRESS = '0x' & Hex($iv_Data[1] + $av_Offset[$i])
        DllCall($AH_HANDLE[0], 'int', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'int', $AH_HANDLE[1], 'int', $IV_ADDRESS, 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($V_BUFFER), 'int', DllStructGetSize($V_BUFFER), 'int', '')
        If @error Then
            SetError(7)
            Return 0
        EndIf
        MsgBox(0,0,$iv_Data[1])
        $iv_Data[1] = DllStructGetData($V_BUFFER, 1)
    EndIf

Next
$iv_Data[0] = $IV_ADDRESS
Return $iv_Data

EndFunc   ;==>_MemoryPointerRead
```

**I gave me 2 results, and the results of AutoIt is true !
I checked in C# code, but I don't have any idea.**

Comment: You can't add pointers among them and the read memory and expect the result you want. You have to read memory and add offsets or pointers to the memory read you already did.

Comment: Share your offsets and addresses and maybe I can write it down for you in c#